# How to use close button as minimize in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use Close (Cross) Button as Minimize button. It is exactly like what we see in Skype.

[image]

I know we can simply disable the Close button by setting ControlBox property to false or we can disable by creating params. But **I want that the Close button should be visible, enabled and working, just the work should be to minimize!**

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this `WinForms?` if so handle the close event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking a lot of time for searching for me but I guess this is something different, this is saving text of a textbox when form is closing but I simply want that when we click on Close button, the form does not closes rather it minimizes (like in Skype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is WinForms, you can handle the `FormClosing` event to accomplish this and set `e.Cancel` to true so the form does not actually get closed after you minimize it:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

And similarly with WPF using the `Closing` event:

```
Private Sub Window_Closing(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Minimized
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Take care.

Comment: Hi, it works. but it makes the command "me.close()" not working.

Comment: @TonyTong -- Right before you call `me.close()`, set a boolean value.  Then inside the `FormClosing` event handler, query that value to determine if you're closing programmatically.

Answer (score 7):

That's what the FormClosing event helps you do.  It is *very* important that you use it responsibly and don't prevent the user from shutting down his machine.  Or get nagged that your program is not playing along, the more typical outcome these days.  You have to pay attention to the reason the window is getting closed.  Thus:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. I can surely add this to the previous code told by roryap.